# Monitoring RTS/DTR Line In PySerial

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I'm working on an RS232 software project that uses RTS/DTR as control inputs for some software. Is there a way to monitor an RTS or DTR line for state change in PySerial? I'm struggling to find examples of monitoring RTS or DTR lines in Python, with the goal of essentially triggering a function while an RTS/DTR line is set.

Thanks!

Comment: What does the documentation say about rts/dtr?

Comment: I went digging, and really couldn't find much about reading RTS/DTR states, the closest thing I can find is it's behavior when a port is opened. "The RTS and DTR lines are switched when the port is
opened. This may cause some processing or reset on the connected device. In such a cases an immediately
following call to write() may not be received by the device."

Comment: Did you see [this](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.dtr) entry about `dtr`?

Comment: I see that a real example would be helpful, however. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I expect you have to poll it: `if port.dtr:`

Comment: A serial port (i.e. UART) would use RTS and  DTR for hardware handshaking, aka flow control.  Typically the hardware or the device driver can be configured to implement the handshaking.  With an SoC if you want to use these signals as general purpose input/output, then these pins would not be multiplexed for UART assignment, but rather set aside for GPIO use.

Answer (score 0):

The input signal of RS232C are CTS/DSR/RI/CD.

You and your project members may be misunderstanding the RS232C specifications.

RTS/DTR are output signal controlled by the program you make, not input signal.

You can know what you have set, or what the default state is, even if you have not set it, but it does not change due to external factors.

[pySerial API](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html)

It is possible that the RTS/DTR signal line may change undesirably due to a hardware problem such as a break in the line or a short-circuit with something, but it is not possible for the program to know it, and it is not in a state where communication is possible.

---

Another possibility is that hardware flow control is enabled and the serial port input buffer is set small, or even if the buffer is set large, the peer sends more data.

The device driver automatically controls the signal lines to prevent input data overflow.

It is due to lack of consideration of serial port settings and program specifications, and it is considered correct programming to prevent such state changes as much as possible.

---

There seems to be no event-driven programming interface for PySerial.

[cts](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.cts)
[dsr](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.dsr)

You wrote that you want to call a function when CTS/DSR are turned on, but on the contrary you may check the state of CTS/DSR when you call the function?

If you really want to perform event-driven programming with CTS/DSR signals, it is a method to create a software loop that monitors CTS/DSR signals as the main routine, detect the timing when the CTS/DSR signal changes from OFF to ON, and call the corresponding function.

Note that if the CTS/DSR signal monitoring by the main routine is not performed intermittently between sleeps, the CPU will become busy and the system will not operate properly.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I think I had myself confused as to which bits do what. In reality, I need to monitor CTS or DSR. I hope that makes sense..